# How to use evaluate and predict functions in keras implementation of SincNet?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

thanks for your atention, I'm developing an automatic speaker recognition system using SincNet.

> Ravanelli, M., & Bengio, Y. (2018, December). Speaker recognition from raw waveform with sincnet. In 2018 IEEE Spoken Language Technology Workshop (SLT) (pp. 1021-1028). IEEE.

Since the network is coded in Pytorch I searched and found a Keras implementation here https://github.com/grausof/keras-sincnet. I adapted the train.py code to train a Sincnet with my own data  in Tensorflow 2.0, and worked fine, I saved only the weights of my trained network, my training data has shape 128,3200,1 for inputs and 128 for labels per batch

```
#Creates a Sincnet model with input_size=3200 (wlen), num_classes=40, fs=16000
redsinc = create_model(wlen,num_classes,fs)

#Saves only weights and stopearly callback
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='checkpoints/SincNetBiomex3.hdf5',verbose=1, 
save_best_only=True, monitor='val_accuracy',save_weights_only=True)
stopearly = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy',patience=3,verbose=1)
callbacks = [checkpointer,stopearly]

# optimizer = RMSprop(lr=learnrate, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-8)
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=learnrate)

# Creates generator of training batches
train_generator = batchGenerator(batch_size,train_inputs,train_labels,wlen)
validinputs, validlabels = create_batches_rnd(validation_labels.shape[0],
validation_inputs,validation_labels,wlen)

#Compiling model and train with function fit_generator
redsinc.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',  optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

history = redsinc.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=N_batches, epochs = epochs, 
verbose = 1, callbacks=callbacks, validation_data=(validinputs,validlabels))
```

The problem came when I tried to evaluate the network, I didn't use the code found in test.py, I only loaded the weights I previously saved and use the function evaluate, my test data had the shape 1200,3200,1 for the inputs and 1200 for labels.

```
# Create a Sincnet model and load previously saved weights
redsinc = create_model(wlen,num_clases,fs)
redsinc.load_weights('checkpoints/SincNetBiomex3.hdf5')

test_loss, test_accuracy = redsinc.evaluate(x=eval_in,y=eval_lab)

RuntimeError: You must compile your model before training/testing. Use `model.compile(optimizer, 
loss)`.
```

Then I added the same compile code I used for training:

```
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
redsinc.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Then rerun the test code and got this:

```
 WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\atenc\Anaconda3\envs\py3.7-tf2.0gpu\lib\site- 
 packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py:1781: calling 
 BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is 
 deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

 Instructions for updating:
 If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.

 ValueError: A tf.Variable created inside your tf.function has been garbage-collected. Your code needs to keep Python references to variables created inside `tf.function`s.

A common way to raise this error is to create and return a variable only referenced inside your function:

@tf.function
def f():
  v = tf.Variable(1.0)
  return v

v = f()  # Crashes with this error message!

The reason this crashes is that @tf.function annotated function returns a **`tf.Tensor`** with the **value** of the variable when the function is called rather than the variable instance itself. As such there is no code holding a reference to the `v` created inside the function and Python garbage collects it.

The simplest way to fix this issue is to create variables outside the function and capture them:

v = tf.Variable(1.0)

@tf.function
def f():
  return v

f()  # <tf.Tensor: ... numpy=1.>
v.assign_add(1.)
f()  # <tf.Tensor: ... numpy=2.>
```

I don't understand the error since I've evaluated other networks with the same function and never got any problems. Then I decided to use predict function to match predicted labels with correct labels and obtain all metrics with my own code but I got another error.

```
# Create a Sincnet model and load previously saved weights
redsinc = create_model(wlen,num_clases,fs)
redsinc.load_weights('checkpoints/SincNetBiomex3.hdf5')
print('Model loaded')

#Predict labels with test data 
predict_labels = redsinc.predict(eval_in)

Error while reading resource variable _AnonymousVar212 from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/_AnonymousVar212/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
 [[node sinc_conv1d/concat_104/ReadVariableOp (defined at \Users\atenc\Anaconda3\envs\py3.7-tf2.0gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_13649]

 Function call stack:
 keras_scratch_graph
```

I hope someone can tell me what these errors mean and how to solve them, I've searched for solutions to them but most of the solutions I've found don't seem related to my problem so I can't apply those solutions. I'm guessing the errors are caused by the Sincnet layer code, because it is a custom coded layer. The code for Sincnet layer can be found in the github repository in the file sincnet.py.

I appreciate all help I can get, again thank you for your atention.

Answer (score 0):

You should downgrade your tf and keras version, it works to me when I faced the same problem.
Try this keras==2.1.6; tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1